# Renaming Files in Python, Getting FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ctostaine/Box/Junior Year/Spring 2019/INFO-I 211/ctostain_B1_indiv.py", line 32, in <module>
    os.rename(file, file.replace('draft', 'final'))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'blah1(draft).rtf' -> 'blah1(final).rtf'
```

This is my code:

```
import os

#retrieve directory from user
usr_direct = input('Please enter a directory: ')

#put the items in the directory in a list
direct_list = os.listdir(usr_direct)
print(direct_list) #// for testing

#iterate through list and change the items
for file in direct_list:
    if 'draft' in file:
        os.rename(file, file.replace('draft', 'final'))
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error? I'm stuck because I feel like this should work but I have no idea what is stopping it from changing the file names.

Comment: `file` must be a fully qualified file name, complete with the directory.